# Registering events inside a constructor?

Tags: c#, events, constructor, event-handling

I have been playing around with delegates, events, and anonymous methods.  In doing so one point became very clear.

Would it not streamline the process of registering any event methods or delegate functions in the constructor?

My tests shows it works and it prevents you from having to declare them after instantiation (as the constructor of the object does it for you).

In fact, the performance is pretty good.  Are there any drawbacks to using the "this" keyword to refer to the current object when constructing / instantiating the object?

This seems to make a lot of sense to me as all the events would be wired up on instantiation.

Are there any areas this might be an issue?

Example:

```
//Constructor
public SayHello() 
{
  _name = "Unnamed";
  _isUpdated = false;

  // Register event handler via lambda (ananymous method shorthand)
  this.NameChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.message)); };
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a couple of potential problems with this approach.  First, on the more general side, one should usually favour using method overrides over subscribing to self-published events for performance reasons.  Obviously, this isn't possible if the event is exposed by an externally sourced based class that exposes an event without a corresponding overridable method.  However, subscribing to self-published events should be an approach of last resort, not a default approach.

The second potential problem is more serious, but it has to do with what the code triggered by the event does, not which object exposes the event.  For example, consider the following constructor:

```
public Foo(Bar bar)
{
    bar.SomeEvent += (s, e) => this.DoSomething();
}
```

If bar fires SomeEvent on another thread, your Foo instance's DoSomething method could be called before the instance has been fully initialized.  This is a fairly well-documented problem in the Java space (see, for example, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html), but coverage is much sparser for C#/.NET.  http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/06/27/on-partiallyconstructed-objects/ provides some detailed coverage for .NET, but it might be more than you wanted to know...

Comment: Nicole, Excellent points.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  My gut was telling me that the added simplification could be problematic (thus the post).  In testing things may work just fine, but in production Murphy's law will be in effect ... probabilistically, anything that can happen will given enough time.  Given this, if the app in question is multithreaded as you state (e.g. a service or Web Portal) race contention would occur at some point in time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there are any issues. It's up to you to do it in that way. You can use the object itself in its constructor. It would work too, if you omitt `this`.

Comment: That is what I thought.  I find it very hand "not" to have to declare the events at the client side (given that the object can instantiate all the code).  That said, was just looking for any potential pitfalls to consider.  So far I have not come across any ... other than memory usage (minimal concern only when event is not relevant).